# What is the user agent string for surface rt?

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10, user-agent, windows-rt

I'm trying to determine the user agent string for surface RT for testing purposes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just do some Google'ing and you will find your answer.

[Internet Explorer 10 User-agent string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh920767%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> **Internet Explorer 10 on Windows RT:**
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; ARM; Trident/6.0)

*Update after comment below*

The link above also states:

> **Identifying touch-enabled systems**
> *Internet Explorer 10 introduces the "Touch" UA string token. If this token is present at the end of the UA string, the computer has touch capability, and is running Windows 8 (or later). This UA string will be transmitted on a touch-enabled system running Windows 8.* 
> **Note** *Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 7 will never report a UA string with the "Touch" token.*
>
> **Internet Explorer 10 on Windows RT with Touch enabled:**
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; ARM; Trident/6.0; Touch)

---

**Update for Internet Explorer 11**

[User-agent string changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Here is what's reported for Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 8.1:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

Here is the string for Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

If you compare these values to those reported by earlier versions of Internet Explorer, you'll find the following changes:

- The compatible ("compatible") and browser ("MSIE") tokens have been removed.
- The "like Gecko" token has been added (for consistency with other browsers).
- The version of the browser is now reported by a new revision ("rv") token.

Comment: not quote pwned considering other devices have more in their user agent string than just the browser type.

Comment: @Kristian did you follow the link?  It has what you are looking for.

Comment: oh, i missed the stack of pwncakes sitting on the bottom. thx

Comment: It seems that the `Touch;` keyword appears to also show on RT, although the MS docs don't seem to say this, so maybe only some RT tablets have the extra Touch keyword? `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; ARM; Trident/6.0; Touch)` This is second hand information from http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie10-windows_rt/mobile-browser-setting-for-ie/b58f9dbb-2227-4aa9-bdf8-045d4c3db871#allReplies

Comment: Miguel, in spite your rude intro this is now the first result in Google. :)

Answer (score 4):

I went to a Microsoft retail location yesterday (November 13, 2012) and used IE to browse to http://whatsmyuseragent.com/ in both Metro and Desktop modes.

Here is the user agent given in both cases:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; ARM; Trident/6.0; Touch)
```

Answer (score 4):

For those interested.  Here is the User Agent string for a Surface Pro (128Gb):

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64; Trident/6.0; Touch)
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, everyone is wrong. The actual user agent that comes up in metro mode is

> Mozilla/4.0 (Compatible; msie 7.0; windows nt 6.2; arm; trident/6.0;
>   touch; .net4.0e; .net4.0c; tablet PC 2.0; Version).

Comment: @Kristian msie 7.0 - really?

Comment: @jim can you tell us more about how you acquired this data?

Comment: Actually, you are wrong!!! The page you used to test this used compatibility mode (documentMode 7). The signs of this are "Compatible;" and "msie 7.0". Although you did use MSIE 10.0 on RT, since the "touch" and "arm" keywords appear in the user agent string.

Comment: Edit: And I am wrong too: the "Compatible;" is always there (and nothing to do with compatibility mode).

Answer (score 2):

This is what I get when I visit the whatsmyuseragent site:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

surface RT will run only IE 10.
The User Agent string is
  `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; ARM; Trident/6.0)`

(source: this [MSDN blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/07/12/ie10-user-agent-string-update.aspx))
This type of information is typically published well in advance of the delivery of the underlying browsers / machines, because of the interest Web Browser manufacturers have in seeing the new browsers well supported by most Web Sites.

Answer (score 0):

UserAgent for devices -

**IE desktop** -      "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.3; rv:11.0) like Gecko"

**IE Surface Pro** - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E;  Tablet PC 2.0; rv 11.0)  like Gecko"

**Edge desktop** - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; ServiceUI 9) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36 Edge/15.15063"

**Edge surface**  - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; ServiceUI 13) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134"

By looking at the above user agents we don't have any clear distinguish between desktop and surface pro for Edge(IE is having Tablet PC check available ). So here to detect the window device first(surface pro is window tablet) and then verify if the device is touch device.

window + touch: true - surface pro

window + touch: false - desktop

```
isSurface: function () {
  // Window device Check
  if(!!navigator.userAgent.match(/Win/)) { 
  // Check if the device is touch               
  return !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Tablet PC/i) || "ontouchstart" in document.documentElement; 
  }
}
```