# How to detect only Microsoft Surface tablets using javascript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone please assist me in detecting "Microsoft Surface" tablets, using javascript / jQuery?  I need to add / remove certain js & css to / from my web pages, when the page opens in Surface tabs only?  I have searched many forums, but not received any concrete solutions yet.  Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [What is the user agent string for surface rt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076839/what-is-the-user-agent-string-for-surface-rt)

Comment: I am also looking for the same thing did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

this code returns true on Surface, Edge browser

```
    if (window.navigator.pointerEnabled && navigator.maxTouchPoints > 1) {
        ...your function goes here...
    }
```

you should use maxTouchPoints > 1, because chrome returns "1" on a desktop. However, browsers on touch devices returns 10

Answer (score 1):

I'm using combination of the regex from [detectmobilebrowser.com](http://detectmobilebrowser.com) to detect none mobile browser and ontouchstart/maxTouchPoints to check it is touch enabled device.

```
window.is_touch_device = 'ontouchstart' in window || navigator.maxTouchPoints;

window.is_mobile_browser = false;

(function(a,b){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))window.is_mobile_browser=true;})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera,'http://detectmobilebrowser.com/mobile');

if( !window.is_mobile_browser && window.is_touch_device )
    window.is_ms_surface = true;
else
    window.is_ms_surface = false;
```

Comment: Nice nice ! Look like ultimate solution.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the detection code used in our projects.

```js
function isSurface() {
  const isWindows = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Windows') > -1;
  const maxTouchPoints = navigator.maxTouchPoints || navigator.msMaxTouchPoints;
  const isTouchable = 'ontouchstart' in window
    || maxTouchPoints > 0
    || window.matchMedia && matchMedia('(any-pointer: coarse)').matches;

  return isWindows && isTouchable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following link should possible give you an idea on how to sniff on what you want.

[JavaScript Window Navigator](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_nav_all)

Hope this is help full to you.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as the surface is just a windows machine with touch enabled, I am using this to detect it:

```
if (window.navigator.msPointerEnabled && navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0) {
  // functions here
}
```

Comment: Is not that embracing a large amount of devices rather than just Surfaces?