# CSS Media Query to tell if mobile or desktop

Tags: css

I just need a boolean to say whether the device is a desktop or not because the design team has given us requirements to behave differently depending on if the webpage is run on a desktop or a tablet. We can assume tablets mean iOS and Android, and desktop is Linux, Windows, MacOS. A Surface Pro would count as desktop. We cannot make any assumptions based on the screen size. There are large tablets and small desktops.

More broadly, we are using Expo React-Native (managed) web target, if CSS cannot provide this information.

Comment: Are they really wanting to detect desktop or mobile, the distinction is pretty subjective, or are they wanting to detect certain capabilities and facilities, like whether the user is using a mouse? Even that sort of thing is woolly because users can switch.

Answer (score 0):

CSS itself cannot detect Surface Pro well, you should use JavaScript instead.

It's not difficult to detect the operating system, but for Surface Pro, it is actually a tablet, but you counted it as a desktop.

[Here is a rough way to do so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35168597/how-to-detect-only-microsoft-surface-tablets-using-javascript-jquery) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076839/what-is-the-user-agent-string-for-surface-rt), but the result is not guaranteed, since it's based on the User Agent string.

Comment: Surface Pro might have a tablet form, but it really is a desktop / laptop. It does not run a mobile OS and still has a keyboard, mouse cursor.

Comment: So if it is easy to detect the OS I am happy to use that to define mobile as Android || iOS. Do you know how I can get the OS as a string?

Comment: Check the links in my answer. You can also Google it.